# Batch Export Symbols to SVG - Illustrator

Tags: javascript, svg, batch-processing, symbols, adobe-illustrator

**Question:**

I've created a script that iterates through all symbols in an Illustrator document and exports them as PNGs.

I need it to work for SVGs as well, however, it's not as simple as just changing the file-type.

Because of Illustrator's default behaviour of making a recently saved svg the `app.activeDocument`, the `for` loop nests new directories for each symbol.

e.g.

```
exports/
  symbol01.svg
  exports/
    symbol02.svg
      exports/
        symbol03.svg
        etc..
```

I'm pretty sure the problem lays between `//create directory` and `//choose directory`, but I can't for the life of me figure it out.

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var symbolCount = doc.symbols.length;

if (symbolCount >= 1) {

   if (confirm("Are all your layers hidden?")) {

      // create temp layer
      doc.layers.add();

      for (var i = 0; i < doc.symbols.length; i++) {

         // place a symbol instance - temp
         var s = doc.symbolItems.add(doc.symbols[i]);

         // create directory 
         var dest = new Folder(doc.path + "/exports"); 
         if (!dest.exists) dest.create();

         // choose directory
         dest.changePath(doc.symbols[i].name);

         // export symbols
         saveSVG(dest);

         // delete temp symbol instance
         s.remove();
      }
      // remove temp layer
      doc.layers[0].remove();
   }

   function saveSVG(file) {
      // save options
      var type = ExportType.SVG;
      var options = new ExportOptionsSVG();

      // export
      doc.exportFile(file, type, options);
   }

} else {

   alert("You don't have any symbols in this document");

}
```

Having a way to store the initial `app.activeDocument` would probably fix the issue, but I can't figure out how to do that.. if that's even the best way?

**Bonus:**

Another problem with this script is the artboard doesn't resize to the symbols, so I found a function `fitArtboardToSelectedArt()` which I've tried implementing with no success.. can anyone can explain how it should work?

PS. Here's a link for the Illustrator scripting documentation: http://adobe.ly/1JxLlUK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out :)

Feel free to use the following script if you need to do the same.

```
/*
 * Export Symbols as SVGs - Illustrator
 * --------------------------------------
 * Created By Shane Parsons - 30PT Design Inc.
 * http://30ptdesign.com/
 */

var doc = app.activeDocument;
var symbolCount = doc.symbols.length;

if (symbolCount >= 1) {

    if (confirm("Are all your layers hidden?")) {

        // choose directory
        var dest = Folder(doc.path).selectDlg();

        // folder chosen
        if (dest) {

            // create temp layer
            doc.layers.add();

            // create temp artboard
            doc.artboards.add(doc.artboards[0].artboardRect);

            // get temp artboard
            var tempAB = doc.artboards.getActiveArtboardIndex();

            // loop through symbols
            for (var i = 0; i < doc.symbols.length; i++) {

                // place a symbol instance - temp
                var symbol = doc.symbolItems.add(doc.symbols[i]);

                // resize artboard
                doc.artboards[tempAB].artboardRect = doc.visibleBounds;
                app.redraw();

                // choose directory
                var filename = doc.symbols[i].name;

                // export symbols
                saveSVG(dest, filename);

                // delete temp symbol instance
                symbol.remove();
            }
            // remove temp layer
            doc.layers[0].remove();

            // remove temp artboard
            doc.artboards[tempAB].remove();
        }
    }

    function saveSVG(dest, filename) {
        // save options
        var type = ExportType.SVG;
        var options = new ExportOptionsSVG();

        // file
        var file = new File(dest + "/" + filename);

        // export
        doc.exportFile(file, type, options);
    }

} else {
    alert("You don't have any symbols in this document");
}
```

Comment: Note: Any images in the document seem to be repeatedly copied over with the svgs for some reason.. The only fix at the moment is to ensure you dont have any images in the document

Comment: Note: This script seems to have issues since dynamic symbols were introduced. I wouldn't recommend using at this point.